# URL Rewrite in IIS and error 'The page isn’t redirecting properly'

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I try to rewrite `url` like below.

`mail.test.com` must redirect to `https`. Other than `test` it's fine to `http`.

```
<match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mail\.test\.com$" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Redirect"  url="https://mail.test.com/{R:1}" />
```

But I got an error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> An error occurred during a connection to mail.test.com.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

SSL certificate and others are fine. If I don't write this rule, it works on `https`, but others also redirect to `https`. What I am missing here?

Comment: I had a simmillar issue i have Changed `pattern=off` and it did the trick for me

Comment: Nop it's not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following. It worked when I performed a quick test with different domains linked to a single website in IIS.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(mail\.test\.com)$" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://mail.test.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When working with redirect rules it is best to clear the browser cache after each change. Otherwise the browser will use the old redirect from cache. Most browser cache data can be cleared with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: I got `500 - Internal server error.` when use your rule. :(

Comment: Hmmm, strange. It worked on my IIS test enviroment. What is the detailed error message?

Comment: Yap your solution work's after restart IIS and clear cache. Thanks. Glad to give my rep for working solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="mail\.test\.com$" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://mail.test.com/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

*Note: Please use chrome://net-internals to clear cache*